# Get String Array from String.xml in ListView

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, string

Im working on download images and from web and lazy load in ListView from this website - http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134.

However, I want to customize the textview on the listview. I want my textview extract the string from string-array in string.xml instead of code `holder.text.setTexr("Title " + position)`

Please help me as I am a beginner. I am Appreciated. Thanks.

XML:

```
 <string-array name="titles">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
</string-array>
```

Here is my main activity

```
public class IngredientCategoryMain extends Activity {

ListView list;
CategoryImageAdapter adapter;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredient_category_main);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter=new CategoryImageAdapter(this, mStrings);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public View.OnClickListener listener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
};

public void onItemClick(int mPosition) {
    String tempValues = mTitles[mPosition];
    Toast.makeText(IngredientCategoryMain.this, tempValues, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private String[] mStrings={
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Ic_cake_48px.svg/2000px-Ic_cake_48px.svg.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/04/01/21/30/can-99137_960_720.png",
        "http://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/Gerald_G_Fast_Food_Drinks_(FF_Menu)_9.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/03/25/16/59/apple-297775_960_720.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/16/11/14/mortar-35544_960_720.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/13/10/05/cattle-156498_960_720.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/15/39/acorn-150258_960_720.png",
        "http://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/johnny_automatic_bread_with_knife.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/09/13/00/12/chicken-937584_960_720.jpg",
        "http://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/bowl-of-steaming-soup-01.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/04/02/10/38/fish-304097_960_720.png",
        "http://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/Erbsen-lineart.png"
};
```

Adapter:

```
public class CategoryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

public CategoryImageAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageButton imageButton;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingcategoryrow, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.imageButton=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    holder.text.setText("Title " + position);
    ImageButton imageButton = holder.imageButton;
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], imageButton);
    vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    return vi;
}

private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener{
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        IngredientCategoryMain sct = (IngredientCategoryMain)activity;
        sct.onItemClick(mPosition);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you saying the value of `position` maps directly to the same index within the string array?  So if position was 0, the string value would be 1?

Comment: yes, how can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working my code please use this code:

String.xml

```
 <string-array name="titles">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
        <item>9</item>
        <item>10</item>
        <item>11</item>
        <item>12</item>
    </string-array>
```

.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    String[] title;
    CategoryImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        title=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);

        adapter=new CategoryImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, title);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public class CategoryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

        private Activity activity;
        private String[] data;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public CategoryImageAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
            activity = a;
            data = d;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi=convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null){
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_lv, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                vi.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
                holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

            holder.text.setText("Title " + data[position]);

            return vi;
        }
    }
        public class ViewHolder {
            public TextView text;

        }

}
```

Comment: Here is my .java file

Comment: public class IngredientCategoryMain extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    
    CategoryImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredient_category_main);

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter=new CategoryImageAdapter(this, mStrings);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: How do I add those code you have above into my current .java file. I tried many times but still fail.

Comment: yes add this code .java file    public class IngredientCategoryMain extends Activity {
 ListView lv;
 String[] title;
 CategoryImageAdapter adapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredient_category_main);

  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

   title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);

  adapter = new CategoryImageAdapter(IngredientCategoryMain.this, title);
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);

 }

Comment: download example from github: https://github.com/PrakashGajera/Hello-World - Cassie.L

Comment: I have edited my original post and add in my main activity code. Can you look at it again? the data on the adapter page will link to mString[] 's url. Thanks again!

Comment: please give me your email id and i send full example.

Comment: cassie.leong1832@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

First get the array as

```
String[] mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
```

Then use it as

```
holder.text.setText(mTestArray[position] + position);
```

Get your array in constructor like:

```
public CategoryImageAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);   
}
```

Comment: Should I call String[] mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);    under public View getView?

Comment: No not at all.As get view is called multiple times on scrolling of listview.Simply call this in your adapters constructor.

Comment: I still can't get it right, if you could specific where should I add those code in, I'd appreciate.

Comment: @Cassie.L what's not working could you please specify.

Comment: I have edited my original post and add in my main activity code. Can you look at it again? the data on the adapter page will link to mString[] 's url. Thanks again!

Comment: i've seen you edit but i cant see where u are trying to get the array and set it ti list item.